# HttpClient call keeps on waiting mode but works fine in Console App

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, dotnet-httpclient, httpresponsemessage

Below is the code which works perfectly fine when i execute it on console application.
The line
**var postResponse = await client.SendAsync(req);** give the result when i run the code in console app.

But when iam using this code in WebApi controller, this code halts on this line.

```
 using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {


            var auth = "MTAwNDgucnVsZXNlbmdpbmUuc2VydmljZTp2N3FuY3I4cWlz";
            client.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://federation-sts-stage.accenture.com");
            var req = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, "https://federation-sts-stage.test.com/oauth/ls/connect/token");
            var cont = new FormUrlEncodedContent(bodyContents);
            cont.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/json");
            cont.Headers.ContentLength = Convert.ToInt64("125");
            req.Content = cont;
            req.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Basic " + auth);


            try
            {
                var postResponse = await client.SendAsync(req); // this is where the code keeps on waiting but works fine in console app
                postResponse.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
                responseContents = postResponse.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;


            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                var msg = ex.Message;
                return msg;
            }


            var responseObject = JObject.Parse(responseContents);
            return responseObject.Value<string>("access_token");
        }
```

I have also compared the request object in both the cases (in console app and in webapi controller call) but in both the cases the request object comes out same as below :

```
{Method: POST, RequestUri: 'https://federation-sts-stage.test.com/oauth/ls/connect/token', Version: 1.1, Content: System.Net.Http.FormUrlEncodedContent, Headers:
{
  Authorization: Basic MTAwNDgucnVsZXNlbmdpbmUuc2VydmljZTp2N3FuY3I4cWlz
  Content-Type: application/json
  Content-Length: 125
}}
```

I dont know what iam doing incorrect.

As per the comments, i am putting the whole method which gets called from apicontroller as below, this method works fine from console app but when i call this method from apicontroller its kept on running.

```
public async Task<string> RequestTokenFromIssuer(string username, string password)
    {

        var bodyContents = new Dictionary<string, string>
        {
            { "grant_type", "client_credentials" },
            { "userName", username },
            { "password", password},
            { "scope", "read_rulesengine write_rulesengine" }
        };

        string responseContents = string.Empty;

        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {


            var auth = "MTAwNDgucnVsZXNlbmdpbmUuc2VydmljZTp2N3FuY3I4cWlz";
            client.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://federation-sts-stage.test.com");
            var req = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, "https://federation-sts-stage.test.com/oauth/ls/connect/token");
            var cont = new FormUrlEncodedContent(bodyContents);
            cont.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/json");
            cont.Headers.ContentLength = Convert.ToInt64("125");
            req.Content = cont;
            req.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Basic " + auth);


            try
            {
                var postResponse = await client.SendAsync(req);
                postResponse.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
                responseContents = postResponse.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;


            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                var msg = ex.Message;
                return msg;
            }


            var responseObject = JObject.Parse(responseContents);
            return responseObject.Value<string>("access_token");
        }

    }
```

Comment: Could you please share you WebApi controller code?

Comment: Is that your real auth key?

Comment: Were you able to use Wireshark (or similar) to compare the data passing over the wire? Just to confirm the two are submitting the same https request?

Comment: I have put up the whole method which iam calling from controller

Comment: Please put a breakpoint on `var msg = ex.Message;` Does that breakpoint get hit?

Comment: No the code doesn't hits there.

Comment: Its not the cause of your issue, but you should know that using a `using` statement with HttpClient is a bad idea, see [here](https://aspnetmonsters.com/2016/08/2016-08-27-httpclientwrong/).

Comment: i don't know why downnvote, i have tried many things in order to fix this.

Comment: maccettura -  sorry,  i don't agree as it disposes the instance of httpclient once its job is done.

Comment: @Rpcoder Well thankfully you not agreeing with me is an opinion, not fact.  [Even Microsoft's documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/advanced/calling-a-web-api-from-a-net-client) points out that you should be using a shared static instance.  Relevant quote: `"HttpClient is intended to be instantiated once and reused throughout the life of an application. The following conditions can result in SocketException errors: 1. Creating a new HttpClient instance per request. 2.Server under heavy load."`

Comment: How did you go with my Wireshark suggestion? Did you try the earlier Nick's suggestion of not using `.Result`?

Comment: mjwills : well i did not tried that, thanks though.

Comment: maccettura : well that's informative...i will try not to use HttpClient next time.

Answer (score 2):

I believe your problem actually is on line

```
responseContents = postResponse.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
```

Never, ever to this in an async method.  You should do it like:

```
responseContents = await postResponse.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
```

Comment: the control doesn't reach to this line, as ive said, the code halts at :
**var postResponse = await client.SendAsync(req);** and iam using await on it.